# 'Join attributes' failing to merge data

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, wfs, attribute-joins, spatial-join

In QGIS 3.22.9, I retrieved data from buildings from a WFS. I want to use the 'join attributes by location' to add more data from other layers into the attributes table.
To be precise: if a building is in a certain area (municipality, province, etc.), I want the attributes to state the area it's in, in a newly added column.

I saved the WFS as files on my computer and when using the 'join attributes by location', it seems to be working fine at first. The areas from the original layer appear in the newly created layer. However, all data in the attributes is now "NULL". This also happens when ignoring invalid geometries and setting all CRS to the same setting.

How do I achieve my goal?

Comment: Doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: How is your data (originating from WFS) saved locally, what file format? Did you check the field types you use? If you have e.g. a field typy of integer and try to join a text, the result will be `NULL`. For further help, please post more details (edit the initial question).